# SQL leaderboard display

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, union, leaderboard

I'm trying to display the first 15 players of my leaderboard but I also want to ensure that the player who requested the leaderboard is shown at it, with only one SQL request

Lets reduce the board to 4 players only.

Imagine that I'm (who requested to view the board) ranked on the 2nd place, the board should display the following

```
pos,name
1,bob
2,ME
3,tony
4,andy
```

But lets imagine that I'm ranked at 150th, then the board should come as

```
pos,name
1,bob
2,tony
3,andy
150,ME
```

I'm using the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT name,rating,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM rank AS t2 
WHERE t2.rating > t1.rating) 
AS position FROM rank AS t1 
LIMIT 15
)  

UNION

SELECT name,rating,(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM rank AS t2 
WHERE t2.rating > t1.rating) 
AS position FROM rank AS t1
WHERE t1.name = 'ben'

ORDER BY rating DESC
```

If I'm ranked between the first 15th the board show correctly.
But If I'm past the first 15th the query return 16 rows with me being the last

In short, I want to display 15 players at the leaderboard but one of them MUST be me

edit: Note that two players can be at same rank position

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using SQLite only. MySQL is also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT name,rating,
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM rank AS t2 
WHERE t2.rating > t1.rating
    AND t1.name <> 'ben') 
AS position FROM rank AS t1 
LIMIT 14
)  

UNION

SELECT name,rating,(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM rank AS t2 
WHERE t2.rating > t1.rating) 
AS position FROM rank AS t1
WHERE t1.name = 'ben'

ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Here, instead don't return your own user in the first query and limit it to 14. Then in the second query only return your own user.

Comment: It will return my user twice, one with position 0 and another with the real position

Comment: Just moved the t1.name conditional you added to the outside select and it worked
Thanks!